# delete lines between two strings powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file in below format:

```
line1  
line2  
Notes:some text here   
and also some text here  
Path : a path   
line3   
line4   
Notes:some text here   
and also some text here  
and some text here    
Path : a path  
line5   
line6   
Notes:  
some text here   
and also some text here  
and some text here    
Path : a path
```

Trying to delete the line with notes and delete all the text before Path. I want the output look like this:

```
line1  
line2  
Path : a path   
line3   
line4   
Path : a path  
line5  
line6  
Path : a path 

itried below code:  

    $File = 'D:\test.txt'
    $text = Get-Content -Path 'D:\test.txt'
    $Pattern = '(?m)^Notes:[\r\n]+.*?[\r\n]Path[\r\n]'
    $text -replace $Pattern, ' ' | 
    Out-File -FilePath $File -Force
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? share some code?

Comment: Please copy/paste the code you are trying to make work. Tell what it is doing, including copy/paste of any error message text.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please be aware this is not a code writing service. Instead this is more along the lines to help you figure out issues that have you stuck in your own development. Please show code or explain what issues you are getting.

Comment: `(Get-Content .\sample.txt -Raw) -Replace "(?sm)^Notes:.*?(?=^Path)"` See an explanation of the RegEx [here](https://regex101.com/r/3WKEdQ/1)

Comment: Thanks @LotPings  It woked well!!